# transaction not working in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, transactions, controllers

I have a problem with transactions in laravel.
When I try to do this operation with the following code, the error appears on the screen as if I had no transaction.

```
\DB::transaction(function() use ($movement, $movementRows) {
   $movement->save();
   $movement->rows()->saveMany($movementRows);
});
```

and when I try to do it with the code below the first object is saved although the second one fails.

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
try {
     $movement->save();
     $movement->rows()->saveMany($movementRows);
      \DB::commit();
      $success = true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $success = false;
    \DB::rollback();
}

if ($success) {
    // the transaction worked ...
}
```

Comment: PHP 7.1.7. Laravel 5.1

Comment: What error appears?

Comment: what is wrong in the query, my tests are doing with a wrong foreign key.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you are using engine that supports transactions. InnoDB supports transactions but MyIsam doesn't. So open your database for example in PhpMyAdmin and make sure all tables are set to InnoDB and not MyISAM (assuming you are using MySQL - you haven't mentioned what database you are using).

Comment: Yes, I'm using MySQL and the tables engine is InnoDB

Comment: Ok, are you using latest Laravel 5.1 version? For 1st code exceptions are not caught, they only rollback transaction and rethrow the exception. In both cases transactions should work. What exact exception is thrown? Are you 100% sure, that movement record is created here?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS). I wrote a try-catch section in the first code and the same thing happens: saves the first record even though the second one fails

Comment: Ok, but as I said what's the exact exception? Maybe it's important to determine what's happening in here because normally it should work without any problem.

Comment: PDOException {#664
    #message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`siie_cartro`.`wms_mvt_rows`, CONSTRAINT `wms_mvt_rows_item_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `erpu_items` (`id_item`) ON DELETE CASCADE)"

Comment: To be honest I don't know why transaction is not rolled back, in theory it should be. To solve this you should fix your code or make column as nullable but it still doesn't the question why transaction is not completely rolled back.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep making changes and trying other things